# Add white space below a table on a page

Tags: html, css

I appreciate that this question has been asked many times but nothing I have looked at has helped me.

Basically, I have a basic table. All I want is to have a bit of white space UNDER the last table (Other Important Pages) but I can't seem to accomplish this.

See here: http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/SiteMap.php

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `<br>` will work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `#page-container` div.

Answer (score 7):

Add a bottom margin to the table.

```
Text Before Table
<table STYLE="margin-bottom: 30px;"><tr><td>Text In Table</td></tr></table>
Text After Table
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tired and it didn't work, thanks anyway.

Comment: I added the bottom margin to the "Apple Pages" table with Firebug in Firefox and it added space underneath.  Under which table are you trying to add space where it is not working?

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the most important part, I'd like it on the last table. I tried "margin-bottom" but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<br />` tags between the tables or add `margin-bottom: XXpx` to the styling.